# Error installing Wordpress to Plesk

Tags: wordpress, installation, vps, plesk

I'm having problems trying to install Wordpress to Plesk on my VPS. Everytime i go install wordpress it gets 100% then shows this message?

ERROR: Call to undefined method PHosting_Apache::getPHPCliPath() (Adapter.php:134)

I have re-imaged the server a few times now and still get the same problem.

Server Software :   CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 12 (64-bit)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of microupdates was not completed successfully. Re-install micro updates by executing the below command:

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller --install-component base  --select-product-id plesk --select-release-current  --reinstall-patch

Comment: Unfortunatley this did not work... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks like that Plesk core packages are not installed properly. I suggest you run /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller manually and re-select          1. [*] Base packages of Parallels Plesk Panel   <--- Base package/Microupdate
 2. [*] Parallels Plesk Panel    <--- Core packages

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did that helped:

Install PHP 5.6 (or latest)

[Find Plesk Add/Remove Components][1]

[Locate PHP installation (mine was here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MAIf.png)

[Drill down into PHP option][3]

[Install latest PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb8gN.png)

I went back and installed wordpress and it went through. Hope this helps

Comment: Why two links are missing?